# Optimizing python for loops numpy

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, vectorization, conv-neural-network

I am implementing the Convolutional Layer for a Neural Network by hand (requirements) and it is excruciatingly slow (12 hrs per experiment?)

Unfortunately I am not very good in python or numpy for that matter and I have no clue how to get rid of the for loops which cause this.

I have tried to use numba with the @jit(nopython=true) annotation, but it is still horribly slow. Can someone help me rewrite the method in an optimized way? or at least point me in the right direction?

I mention I have to use python, so no way to get rid of that.

```
@jit(nopython=True)
def sum1(sliced, kernel, bias):
      return np.sum(sliced*kernel) + bias

@jit(nopython=True)
def getfprop1(inputs, kernels, biases, noinputs, nooutputsc, kdim1, kdim2, outdim1, outdim2):
   outputs = zero(noinputs, nooutputsc, outdim1, outdim2)

   for i in range (noinputs):
        input = inputs[i, :, :, :]
        for h in range(outdim1):
            for w in range(outdim2):
                for c in range(nooutputsc):
                    vert_start = h
                    vert_end = h + kdim1
                    horiz_start = w
                    horiz_end = w + kdim2
                    sliced = input[:, vert_start:vert_end, horiz_start:horiz_end]
                    outputs[i, c, h, w] = sum1(sliced, kernels[c,:,:,:], biases[c])
return outputs
```

Comment: Any reason on not using built-in convolution func - https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve2d.html? I guess this would be more appropriate - https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.1/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.convolve1d.html

Comment: They do not allow us to :(

Comment: Issue seems to be `np.sum(`. You need to "hand-craft" that as well.

Comment: You can probably gain a few by inlining `sum1` instead of calling it as a function, and avoid unnecessary allocations in the 4 levels deep for loop. It would not matter in C, but in Python it can.

Comment: I did that because in numba they suggested to decorate with jit any function we are using http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.35.0/user/jit.html#compilation-options section 1.3.2

Comment: How about fft? Not allowed either?

Comment: fft? I have never heard of that

Comment: fft = Fast Fourier Transform, for convolution. There is a `parallel=True` option for numba, too.

Comment: Stands for fast Fourier transform. Can be used to speed up [convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem). Numpy has an [`fft` module](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.fft.html).

Comment: I think that a version of numpy sliding window might be more of help for me, but I will try!